# How to write multiline strings in SML?

Tags: string, sml

How can I write a string that spans multiple lines?

I tried to use the line continuation character `\` at the end like many other languages, but it does not seem to work. The following:

```
val s = "line1\
line2";
```

generates an error:

```
/tmp/...:1: error: unexpected character l in \ ... \
/tmp/...:1: error: no matching quote found on this line
```

Not using any line continuation as follows generates a similar error:

```
val s = "line1
line2";
```

*What's the correct way to write a multiline string?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the backslash at the beginning of the next lines as well :

```
print "this is\
\ a string on\
\ 3 lines\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SML/NJ and you don't care much about portability, there's a lesser known feature that could give you not only multiline strings, but also variable interpolation. SML/NJ supports an extensible quotation mechanism, which is described in more detail here: https://www.smlnj.org/doc/quote.html

Now, to solve your problem, we could define the following *quotation parser*. I'm calling it `s` to draw a parallel with Scala's `s"..."` syntax, which will become clearer in a few moments.

```ml
val s : string SMLofNJ.frag list -> string =
  let
    fun fold (SMLofNJ.QUOTE s, acc) = acc ^ s
      | fold (SMLofNJ.ANTIQUOTE s, acc) = acc ^ s
  in
    List.foldl fold ""
  end
```

Notice that it makes use of the `SMLofNJ` structure to access compiler-specific datatypes and values (`frag`, `QUOTE` and `ANTIQUOTE`).

We can now use the above like this (make sure you're using the command line option `-Cparser.quotations=true`):

```ml
$ sml -Cparser.quotations=true
- val a = "var";
val a = "var" : string
-
- val b = `this is a raw quotation using ^a`;
val b = [QUOTE "this is a raw quotation using ",ANTIQUOTE "var",QUOTE ""] :
  string SMLofNJ.frag list
-
- val c = s`this is an interpolated string: ^a`;
val c = "this is an interpolated string: var" : string
-
- print c;
this is an interpolated string: varval it = () : unit
-
- val d = s`this
… is
… a
… multiline string: ^a`;
val d = "this\nis\na\nmultiline string: var" : string
-
- print d;
this
is
a
multiline string: varval it = () : unit
```

As you can see, using quotations in conjunction with a very simple custom parser (the `s` function), we can get multiline interpolated strings in SML/NJ.

In my personal library, I've defined it in a bit more structured way:

````ml
structure Strings =
  struct
    structure Interpolated =
      struct
        local
          open SMLofNJ
        in
          (**
           * Support for multiline, interpolated strings.
           *
           * NB: requires SML/NJ quotations: sml -Cparser.quotations=true.
           *
           * ```sml
           * - open Strings.Interpolated;
           * - val v = "val";
           * val v = "val" : string
           * - val j = s`{
           * =   "key": "^v"
           * = }`;
           * val j = "{\n  \"key\": \"val\"\n}" : string
           * ```
           *)
          val s : string frag list -> string =
            let
              fun fold (QUOTE s, acc) = acc ^ s
                | fold (ANTIQUOTE s, acc) = acc ^ s
            in
              List.foldl fold ""
            end
        end
      end
  end
````